# How do I split a JSON object based on the existence of a text value?

Tags: python, json

I'm using the Reqests module in Python to pull information from a REST API. The data is returned in JSON - each element of the JSON array represents a user, the groups child array represents their Active Directory groups. A sample entry looks like this:

```
{
                    "id": 0101010101,
                    "createdAt": 111111,
                    "displayName": "Jones, Steve",
                    "firstName": "Steve",
                    "lastName": "Jones",
                    "groups": [
                        "All Users",
                        "Anyville Users (WIN10)",
                        "Windows 10 Users"
                    ],
                    "deviceCount": 0
                },
{
                    "id": 0101010102,
                    "createdAt": 111111,
                    "displayName": "Smith, Dave",
                    "firstName": "Dave",
                    "lastName": "Smith",
                    "groups": [
                        "All Users",
                        "Faketown Users (WIN7)",
                        "Windows 7 Users"
                    ],
                    "deviceCount": 0
                }
```

How do I iterate through the JSON array, evaluate whether the groups array contains text matching any of a set of locations (Anyville, Faketown, Nowehereland), and put that row into a separate object for each location? The closest I've come is the following:

```py
faketownUsers = {}
response = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers)

ir = json.loads(response.text)
data = ir['result']['searchResults']
for row in data:
    if "Faketown" in str(row):
        faketownUsers.extend(row)
```

Comment: What is actually in `data`?  What are the issue(s) with your code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `row` represents the full dictionary, but you need to look inside the `groups` item.
`groups` is a `list`, and the string you're looking for is part of an item of that `list`.
There many ways to go about it, I'll give two examples, method 1:

```py
locations = {'Faketown': []}
for row in data:
    for group in row['groups']:
        if 'Faketown' in group:
            locations['Faketown'].append(row)
```

method 2:

```py
locations = {'Faketown': []}
for row in data:
    if 'Faketown' in ''.join(row['groups']):
        locations['Faketown'].append(row)
```

You can add any other location to `locations`.

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'd do something like:

```
# load data, raise an exception on error
res = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
res.raise_for_status()

# get data from json response
data = res.json()['result']['searchResults']

# figure out which user groups match
locations = {'Faketown': [], 'Anyville': []}
for row in data:
    for locname, locarr in locations.items():
        if any(locname in grp for grp in row['groups']):
            locarr.append(row)
```

I've changed a bit of your other code around to check for/handle errors better, mostly by throwing exceptions

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the object into a string to check if it contains a substring instead of checking it into each field.

```
from collections import defaultdict
locations = defaultdict([])

locations_to_check = ['Anyville', 'Faketown', 'Nowehereland']
for row in data:
    for location in locations_to_check:
         if location in str(row['groups']):
            locations[location].append(row)

# output
# {'Anyville': [{...}, {...}], 'Faketown': [{...},{...}]}
```